# Using NSTableView with cocoa binding and Realm

Tags: swift, cocoa, realm, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I am using NSTableView with cocoa binding.
The Array which is binding with my table is causing an issue when I tried to save it to Realm.

> Error : Error Cannot add an object with observers to a Realm

Is there a workaround to use Realm with NSTableview cocoa binding variable?

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var owner: Person?
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    var age = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs") // inverse
}

class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var birthdate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
    let dogs = List<Dog>() // to-many
}
```

.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
@objc dynamic var dogsArray = [Dog]() // Cocoa binding with my NSTableView


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dog1 = Dog(value: [nil, "Fido", 5])
    let dog2 = Dog(value: [nil, "Pluto", 8])
    dogsArray = [dog1,dog2]


    let person = Person(value: ["Alex", Date()])
    person.dogs.append(objectsIn: dogsArray)

    try! realm.write { realm.add(person) }
}
```

Comment: Does `let dog1 = Dog(value: ["Fido", 5])` work for you? It just throws an error for me as it's not initializing the class properly as the keys are not defined.

Comment: yes it does. The error is at line : person.dogs.append(objectsIn: dogsArray)

Comment: I created a brand new Realm project and copy/pasted your code. When I run that code, the error I get is `[General] Invalid value 'Fido' to initialize object of type 'Person': missing key 'name'`which makes sense since the Dog object has a Person owner, not a string.

Comment: I have updated the code, but this is not exactly the same as mine. Despite the error is the same because of the dynamic variable which Realm consider like an observer and cannot be written.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I copy and pasted that code but left `@objc dynamic var dogsArray = [Dog]()` not bound to anything and used it as a class var and it works as expected. A person object was created in realm and had a list of the two dogs. Can I suggest not binding that to the tableView and just populate it using tableView delegate methods?

Comment: What I need is a way to unregister the observer on  "@objc dynamic var dogsArray = [Dog]()" just before I write in realm. But I don't know if it is possible ?